# jQuery css toggle error in IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

**Please note:** Code works in all browsers except IE 8 and below.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6tTcq/ (JS fiddle won't work in IE 8 where the problem is.)

Program: jQuery toggles the css class `._22t` then the class `._22` is hovered over.(Tooltip) Works in all browsers except IE 8 and below.

Problem: Ever since I added the below code to `._22t:hover` the tool tip no longer works in IE 8.

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
background-color: black;
filter: alpha(opacity=10);
```

I can't work out why the filter property would break the css toggle?

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="inter">
    <div class="_0"></div>          
    <div class="_22"><div class="_22t"><p>This is a tooltip. This is the first step for the jquery path system</p><div class="tooltiptail"></div></div></div>       
</div>
```

**jQuery CODE:**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.inter [class]', function(event) {     
        $('._22t').toggle(event.type === 'mouseenter');
   });
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
._22{
    position: absolute;
    left: 271px;
    top: 280px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    cursor: hand; 
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
}

._22t{
    position: relative;
    top: 161px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 110px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: rgb(97, 99, 101);
    background: rgba(99, 100, 103,0.9);
    border: 4px solid rgb(69, 70, 71);
    border: 4px solid rgba(69, 70, 71, 0.9);
    display: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

._22:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    background-color: black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=10);
}

.inter {
    position: relative;
    width: 716px;
    height: 604px;
    background-image: url('0.png');
}
```

When I change display to block on the ._22t class the tooltip appears perfectly. But when I hover over it then disappears. I'm assuming there is an issue with the toggle.

Comment: Are you sure it's not showing at all, or is it just really faint because you set the opacity value to 10%?

Comment: You've checked to make sure IE8 isn't in quirks mode, right? (Make sure there's a valid `DOCTYPE` for starters.)

Comment: @Kolink I tested that and it I'm sure.

Comment: @MattBrowne I am using "<!DOCTYPE html>"

Comment: I wonder if the issue explained in [this comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#2) on MSDN could be related. (If the link doesn't take you to the comment, scroll down to the second user comment.)

Comment: When I change display to block on the ._22t class the tooltip appears perfectly. But when I hover over it then disappears. I'm assuming there is an issue with the toggle.

Comment: @MattBrowne I thought so too. But it doesn't seem to the problem.

Comment: After some testing appears the tooltip can only be seen in the :hover element width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this

$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.inter [class]', function(event) {
$('.' + this.className + 't').toggle(event.type =='mouseenter');
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$.hover(function() { $('._22').show() }, function() { $('_22').hide() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's "hover" function, it will work for keyboard events either:

```
$("<selector>").hover(
  function () {
    $('._22t').show();
  },
  function () {
    $('._22t').hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: Are you use JQuery code in $(document).ready(function(){<your_code>}); ?

Comment: Sure am. I using that over the entire script. @veysiertekin

Comment: After some testing appears the tooltip can only be seen in the :hover element width and height